# Numbers of solutions to $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This is a proof proving that for a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$, $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at most $n$ solutions. Is it correct?

> For $n=1$,
>   $$a_1x+a_0\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
>   has exactly one solution since $\gcd(p,a_1)=1$. Suppose the proposition holds for $n-1$, that is, any polynomial of degree $n-1$ has at most $n-1$ solutions. Let 
>   $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\dots+a_0.$$ If the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$
>   has no solutions, then the statement is true. If it has at least one solution, let $s$ be said solution. Observe that
>   $$f(x)\equiv (x-s)g(x)\pmod{p}\quad g(x)\text{ has degree }n-1.$$
>   Since $g(x)$ has at most $n-1$ solutions and $s$ is one solution, the max number of solutions in the congruence is $n-1+1=n.\quad\square$

Comment: Well, do you understand where you used the primality of $p$?  For instance, $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod {12}$ has four solutions.

Comment: Hmm, actually I don't. what breaks down if you replace $p$ with any integer ?

Comment: Right.  Study the example I mentioned.  We can write $x^2-1\equiv (x+1)(x-1)\equiv (x-5)(x-7) \pmod {12}$.  Note, for instance, that neither $5+1$ nor $5-1$ is $0 \pmod {12}$ though their product is.

Comment: More broadly, the division algorithm (which you implicitly used) only gets you what you want when there aren't zero divisors.

Comment: So having a prime ensure that you won't get those extra solutions since no product of two integers(besides $1$ and multiples of $p$ itself) will be congruent $0$ mod $p$. Is that why a prime is necessary ?

Comment: Aren't we assuming all the coefficients aren't multiples of $p$ ? This proof isn't mine it's from the book I'm using.

Comment: Well, part of it is.

Comment: I think I understand the mistake.

Comment: The proof isn't wrong, so much as it is incomplete.  The author may assume that the reader is familiar with the use of the division algorithm in a field.  But you need primality to get a field.

Comment: Alright thanks!

Comment: Is $P$ is constant prime